# how to identify web page is having address bar or it is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to detect that web app is runing in app mode or in safari mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379867/how-to-detect-that-web-app-is-runing-in-app-mode-or-in-safari-mode)

I want that if my web page opens with address bar on safari it should load browser.css file and if it opened from desktop of iPAd device then it loads withoud address bar then it should use ipad.css file

Comment: @meandmycode can you explain me more how to solve this

Comment: You've already asked this question and received an answer that points you in the right direction (although I'm biased on whether the answer is good as it's my answer).

Comment: When I said you need to ask a new question the question should have been "How do I set a different css file in javascript". I still think before you try anything you need to do some basic background reading on what the difference is between html, css and javascript and how they interact and interface. Here is that link again code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/intro-to-js.html

Comment: Why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379867/how-to-detect-that-web-app-is-runing-in-app-mode-or-in-safari-mode

Comment: @bažmegakapa Whats the why at?

Comment: @EdKirk I asked the op why he duplicated this question.

Answer (score 0):

If there's not much to change, you can use media queries apply styles depending on the height of the viewport: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

```
@media (orientation: portrait, min-height: 800px) { background-color: red; }
```

The problem with this is that you will have to know the resolution beforehand (if its an iPad specific app, this is perfectly usable)

Comment: Please, justify why have you downvoted me, so we all can learn.

Comment: i want that in without address there shows alot of space from botton so that's why  i want to give two css files.

Comment: I have not downvoted you

Comment: You can use media queries to `@import` other stylesheets aswell. take a look at the link.

Comment: <link type="text/css" href="newstyle_tester.css" rel="stylesheet" />
          <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: i am using this css only if i want two files for this how to do

Comment: Look at this: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0 . It's the examples part of the doc, so you can see the various ways of using media queries, like in `<link>`, `@import` and `@media`

Comment: media witdh is same i want to fix other things in css when we have withoud address bar web page

Comment: @user1365106 Please, experiment with the example I've posted or post more info, code and/or objectives so we can have more base to help. Anyway, without JavaScript media queries are the only way of applying styles based device conditions.