# how to detect that web app is running in app mode or in safari mode

Tags: javascript, ipad, html

How to check that a web page is running in safari mode with address bar or in app mode without address bar in iPad

```
             <script>
              if (window.navigator.standalone) {

                  <link type="text/css" href="ipad.css" rel="stylesheet" />



              }


              els{

                  <link type="text/css" href="safari.css" rel="stylesheet" />

              }

              </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

By in app mode I assume you mean when it's launched from the home screen:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {

    /* Launched from home screen code */

}
```

This works on all iOS devices ASAIK.

Comment: can you help me out i have update my code but no any response

Comment: You are now asking a different question which should be in a new question. From that code you seem not to understand the interaction between javascript and html/css. I suggest you follow a basic tutorial on js, such as this one by google http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/intro-to-js.html  this should start you on the track to understand why your code is not doing what you expect.